# Windows Phone: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone

I created a windows phone app in vs2010, when I try to build it I get this error:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I didn't make any modification to the project that vs2010 build, however I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it does happen because of the extension you're using. For example, `NuGet`.

Try to update the `NuGet`, then this problem will get rid hope so. If not, simply uninstall the `NuGet` and then you can install it again later.

`NuGet` is the example, i told you for. This problem may be arising because of extensions like `NuGet` is the answer for your question exactly.